# Can I get jQuery Mobile to respect Shift and Ctrl when a link is clicked on the desktop?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm building a website that needs to feel "appy", the users will be mostly on phones and tablets, but some will be on PCs too.

Through the "hijacking" of links that jQM does to implement AJAX navigation, they essentially break the functionality of "Shift click opens in new window, Ctrl click opens in new tab". I'd like to keep this functionality, for our PC users.

This is not a huge deal, since the vast majority of users won't know of this, but personally, when I'm using a website that doesn't respect this it ticks me off enormously, so I'd like to respect it.

Is there any way to make this work with jQM?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You could follow a responsive design approach. The desktop users should not see a jQM based website.

You could use [Moderniz](http://modernizr.com/) along with [Yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) to implement an approach such as the following:

```
test: Modernizr.mq( "only all and (max-width: 640px)" ),
yep: {
    "jqmcss": "css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css",
    "mcss": "css/mobile.screen.css"
},
nope: {
    //desktop
    "scss": "css/desktop.screen.css"
},
callback: {
    //use the callbacks from above and load jQuery Mobile 1.3.1
    "jqmcss": function( url, result, key ) {
        yepnope({
            load: "js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"
        });
    },
    "scss": function( url, result, key ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You can use Modernizr along with media queries and touch detection to detect whether you are on a mobile, touch based device or you're at anything less than 480px. The appropriate CSS and JS files are dynamically and asynchronously loaded in each case. jQM is loaded only when a mobile device is detected. Note that the above code is incomplete. I've added it in order to give a sense of how this approach works.

In my opinion responsive design is the right way. However, maybe you could try the following "dirty" solutions when you detect that you're on a desktop:

Ctrl + Click:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.button === 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr("href"), '_blank');
    }
});
```

or you could disable Ajax transitions for anchors using:

```
$('a').attr("data-ajax", "false");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I actually *want* most of the goodness that comes from jQM in the desktop too (particularly ajax navigation, which gives you huge speed increases), so the desktop version should definitely use jQM.

As far as the "dirty" solution, any way that I can differentiate between Ctrl and Shift? (new tab vs new window). IOW, can I specify to window.open whether it opens a tab or a window?